# Magento 1.8.1 Frontend incredibly slow on OSX

Tags: magento-1.8, frontend

I have an OSX development environment in which I ported a Magento db that is working fine in production.

My dev environment is using:

- Magento 1.8.1.0
- MySql 5.7.11
- PHP 5.5.30
- Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)

The backend is working fine, however the frontend is incredibly slow (2.5 minutes to load the index.html).

Do you have any idea of what is going wrong?

This are the first lines of my profiler output ordered by time (I am sorry for the pretty bad table format):

`Memory usage: real: 54001664, emalloc: 43746624
Code Profiler   Time    Cnt Emalloc RealMem
mage    292.1082    1   0   0
mage::dispatch::routers_match   291.498 1   0   0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::predispatch 164.4863    1   4,474,112   4,718,592
CORE::create_object_of::Mage_Core_Model_Session 164.4522    2   279,216 262,144
Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start/start    164.4475    1   91,096  262,144
mage::dispatch::controller::action::cms_index_index 127.0072    1   0   0
mage::dispatch::controller::action::cms_index_index::layout_render  126.8173    1   0   0
frontend/mascagni/mt_colinus/template/page/1column.phtml    126.7907    1   13,076,656  22,806,528
__EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ENT__ 120.2808    26  4,635,184   4,194,304
frontend/mascagni/mt_colinus/template/page/html/header.phtml    118.4312    1   3,421,056   3,670,016
frontend/mascagni/mt_colinus/template/magenthemes/navigation/top.phtml  118.3935    1   2,132,200   2,359,296
frontend/mascagni/mt_colinus/template/magenthemes/productsscroller/productsscroller.phtml   5.1881  1   4,959,856   15,728,640
frontend/mascagni/mt_colinus/template/magenthemes/productslist/productslist.phtml   2.6763  1   709,760 0
frontend/mascagni/mt_colinus/template/magenthemes/productslist/products.phtml   2.6632  1   491,480 0
__EAV_LOAD_MODEL__  2.3984  208 11,420,360  3,932,160
__EAV_COLLECTION_AFTER_LOAD__   1.9576  26  3,239,952   2,883,584
__EAV_LOAD_MODEL_AFTER_LOAD__   1.0366  208 3,548,504   2,883,584
__EAV_LOAD_MODEL_ATTRIBUTES__   0.9912  208 14,450,832  0
frontend/mascagni/mt_colinus/template/catalog/product/price.phtml   0.6862  22  1,891,032   0
mage::dispatch::db_url_rewrite  0.5266  1   61,168  0
__EAV_COLLECTION_LOAD_ATTR__    0.4639  26  420,704 262,144
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_block_product_list_collection    0.3955  2   1,787,800   1,572,864
OBSERVER: review    0.3952  2   1,784,992   1,572,864
OBSERVER: inventory 0.288   66  2,675,256   1,835,008
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_collection_load_after    0.2378  22  3,206,024   2,883,584
mage::dispatch::controller::action::cms_index_index::layout_generate_blocks 0.1612  1   15,425,136  15,204,352
DISPATCH EVENT:catalog_product_load_after   0.0974  44  548,240 0
BLOCK ACTION: checkout_cart_link -> addCartLink 0.0566  1   5,490,824   5,505,024
BLOCK: bestseller   0.0411  1   2,938,944   2,883,584
mage::app::init::stores 0.0344  1   3,654,376   3,670,016`

Comment: Could there be caching set up on production that are not set up or not working on your dev machine?

Comment: I have disabled (from the backend) both the zend cache and the normal cache in my dev enviroment

Comment: Disabling caching in Magento certainly makes things a lot slower, especially with Modules like ManaDev

Comment: If cache is turned off on dev, that's certainly slowing things down, if not the whole cause of the performance difference!

Comment: Actually I enabled and disabled it and doesn't make a noticeable difference :/

Answer (score 0):

To my future self: identify the slow call by means of the profiler, try replacing the same call with a different Magento method

e.g.

Get all subcategories:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($catId);
```

Replaced with:

```
$categoryCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1) //only active categories
    ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1)
    ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $catId)
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```